# ON DUPLICATE multiple update

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I am trying to create a query which will add/update multiple rows at the same time and I am trying to make sure it handles duplicate keys properly by updating all values except the private key which in my case will be `a.id`

```
INSERT INTO products a (a.id, a.price, a.condition, a.link, a.price_updated) 
VALUES ('t1', 11, 'used', 'adasd', 100), ('t2', 11, 'used', 'adasd', 100) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VALUES (a.price, a.condition, a.link, a.price_updated)
```

The above query gives me a right syntax error near the `a (a.id`, what could I be doing wrong?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
INSERT INTO products (id, price, cond, link, price_updated) 
VALUES ('t1', 11, 'used', 'adasd', 100), 
   ('t1', 11, 'used', 'adasd', 2100) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
   price = VALUES(price), 
   cond = VALUES(cond), 
   link = VALUES(link), 
   price_updated = VALUES(price_updated)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9da82/1)

I do not think you can use table aliases for this either, but I may be mistaken.

BTW -- I used cond for the condition field just to make it easier -- replace with your field names (you may need back ticks with condition as I believe it's a reserved word).

Comment: Your right condition is a reserved word, this looks good, thanks

Comment: @mk_89 -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a syntax error because Mysql's [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) statement doesn't allow you to alias the inserted table: You must say `INSERT INTO products (id, ...)`.

Comment: @mk_89 -- that's not the only problem with the query though.  You also need to fix your UPDATE syntax.  See my post above.